# Slow cooker lasagna with a liner

Tags: lasagna

I’m making slow cooker lasagna and want to put a liner in the cooker. Has anyone been successful with this method?

Comment: what kind of liner ? and why ?

Comment: @max I assume the OP is referring to slow cooker liners that are a sort of fairly heatproof plastic bag.  They're useful for very old models in which you can't remove the inner pot to clean it thoroughly, or if you're too  lazy to wash the pot

Answer (score 1):

I was referring to the plastic type disposable liner. I made the lasagna without it anyway, just sprayed the interior with cooking spray. I see no reason for anyone to judge my energy level. BTW the lasagna came out great, just used the noodles right out of the box without preboiling. New favorite method.

Comment: Oh ... sorry ... I thought you were asking about the 'with liner' part if we've been successful.  (which I've never done).  My neighbor would make slow cooker lasagna (without a liner), and I was amazed at how well it came out.